# How to find and remove a cached image?

Tags: 6, database, media

I have an image with url like:

```
http://example.com/index.php?q=sites/default/files/imagecache/node-gallery-display/123.JPG
```

I want to remove this image but don't know where it stored in database.

Whenever I remove `123.JPG` from the path, it is re-generated on the next GET request. 
I removed all nodes with that title from the node table but it had no effect. So I'm have no idea how to find and remove all trace of it from the database. Appreciate your help about it.

Comment: Last time I checked, images are stored in folders and not on the database. So check your `/sites/default/files/imagecache/node-gallery-display/` folder. BTW I hope you're upgrading to 7 or 8 soon. [Drupal 6 end-of-life announcement](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)

Comment: Well, as I said, no matter how many times I delete the image in the folder it is regenerated.

Comment: Yeah, drupal regenerate it whenever needs it. If you want to get rid of it you need to delete the original image, look for:/default/files/123.JPG

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find -name   "123.JPG" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: You should elaborate why this solves this answer. Jand has said, "So I'm have no idea how to find and remove all trace of it from the database." This doesn't explain why a blanket find/remove will solve the issue.